# How to completely evaluate an attribute's parameters in a C# source generator?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

In a source generator, I've found an attribute on a class and resolved its FQN with `GeneratorSyntaxContext.SemanticModel` to, e.g., deal with its name being written with or without "Attribute" in it. How can I resolve the arguments? Basically I want to handle all of these:

```
// class MyAttribute : Attribute
// {
//   public MyAttribute(int first = 1, int second = 2, int third = 3) {...}
//   string Property {get;set;}
// }

[My]
[MyAttribute(1)]
[My(second: 8 + 1)]
[My(third: 9, first: 9)]
[My(1, second: 9)]
[My(Property = "Bl" + "ah")] // Extra, I can live without this but it would be nice
```

Most code I could find, including official samples, just hardcode ArgumentList[0], [1], etc. and the attribute's name written in "short form". Getting the attribute object itself or an identical copy would be ideal (it's not injected by the source generator but ProjectReferenced "normally" so the type is available) but it might be beyond Roslyn so just evaluating the constants and figuring out which value goes where is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can collect necessary information using [syntax notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.generatorinitializationcontext.registerforsyntaxnotifications?view=roslyn-dotnet-4.0.1#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_GeneratorInitializationContext_RegisterForSyntaxNotifications_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_SyntaxReceiverCreator_). Here is a detailed walk-through.

First, register the syntax receiver in your generator.

```cs
[Generator]
public sealed class MySourceGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterForSyntaxNotifications(() => new MySyntaxReceiver());
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        if (context.SyntaxReceiver is not MySyntaxReceiver receiver)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var attributeDefinition in receiver.AttributeDefinitions)
        {
            var usage = attributeDefinition.ToSource();
            // 'usage' contains a string with ready-to-use attribute call syntax,
            // same as in the original code. For more details see AttributeDefinition.

            // ... some attributeDefinition usage here
        }
    }
}
```

`MySyntaxReceiver` does not do much. It waits for the `AttributeSyntax` instance, then creates and passes the `AttributeCollector` visitor to the `Accept()` method. Finally, it updates a list of the collected attribute definitions.

```cs
internal class MySyntaxReceiver : ISyntaxReceiver
{
    public List<AttributeDefinition> AttributeDefinitions { get; } = new();

    public void OnVisitSyntaxNode(SyntaxNode node)
    {
        if (node is AttributeSyntax attributeSyntax)
        {
            var collector = new AttributeCollector("My", "MyAttribute");
            attributeSyntax.Accept(collector);
            AttributeDefinitions.AddRange(collector.AttributeDefinitions);
        }
    }
}
```

All actual work happens in the `AttributeCollector` class. It uses a list of the `AttributeDefinition` records to store all found metadata. For an example of using this metadata, see the `AttributeDefinition.ToSource()` method.

You can also evaluate the `syntax.Expression` property if needed. I didn't do it here.

```cs
internal class AttributeCollector : CSharpSyntaxVisitor
{
    private readonly HashSet<string> attributeNames;

    public List<AttributeDefinition> AttributeDefinitions { get; } = new();

    public AttributeCollector(params string[] attributeNames)
    {
        this.attributeNames = new HashSet<string>(attributeNames);
    }

    public override void VisitAttribute(AttributeSyntax node)
    {
        base.VisitAttribute(node);

        if (!attributeNames.Contains(node.Name.ToString()))
        {
            return;
        }

        var fieldArguments = new List<(string Name, object Value)>();
        var propertyArguments = new List<(string Name, object Value)>();

        var arguments = node.ArgumentList?.Arguments.ToArray() ?? Array.Empty<AttributeArgumentSyntax>();
        foreach (var syntax in arguments)
        {
            if (syntax.NameColon != null)
            {
                fieldArguments.Add((syntax.NameColon.Name.ToString(), syntax.Expression));
            }
            else if (syntax.NameEquals != null)
            {
                propertyArguments.Add((syntax.NameEquals.Name.ToString(), syntax.Expression));
            }
            else
            {
                fieldArguments.Add((string.Empty, syntax.Expression));
            }
        }

        AttributeDefinitions.Add(new AttributeDefinition
        {
            Name = node.Name.ToString(),
            FieldArguments = fieldArguments.ToArray(),
            PropertyArguments = propertyArguments.ToArray()
        });
    }
}

internal record AttributeDefinition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public (string Name, object Value)[] FieldArguments { get; set; } = Array.Empty<(string Name, object Value)>();
    public (string Name, object Value)[] PropertyArguments { get; set; } = Array.Empty<(string Name, object Value)>();

    public string ToSource()
    {
        var definition = new StringBuilder(Name);
        if (!FieldArguments.Any() && !PropertyArguments.Any())
        {
            return definition.ToString();
        }

        return definition
            .Append("(")
            .Append(ArgumentsToString())
            .Append(")")
            .ToString();
    }

    private string ArgumentsToString()
    {
        var arguments = new StringBuilder();

        if (FieldArguments.Any())
        {
            arguments.Append(string.Join(", ", FieldArguments.Select(
                param => string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.Name)
                    ? $"{param.Value}"
                    : $"{param.Name}: {param.Value}")
            ));
        }

        if (PropertyArguments.Any())
        {
            arguments
                .Append(arguments.Length > 0 ? ", " : "")
                .Append(string.Join(", ", PropertyArguments.Select(
                    param => $"{param.Name} = {param.Value}")
                ));
        }

        return arguments.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question about this line: "if (context.SyntaxReceiver is not MySyntaxReceiver receiver)". Pattern matching isn't available below C# 9, and source generators have to target netstandard2.0, which has a max C# version of 7.3. How are you working around this?

Comment: @MattG If you provide `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` in a `PropertyGroup` on the source generator project file you will be able to utilize newer language features on the older framework (yes, I fully understand how unintuitive that sounds haha)

Comment: You may not have to use `preview` and instead could use some other value, YMMV

Comment: This is nice but you are missing the class node information that goes along with that attribute.

Answer (score 1):

On the INamedTypeSymbol/member/whatever that *has* the attributes, you can call GetAttributes(), which gives you an array of AttributeDatas. That'll give you all the attributes for that, so you'll have to filter back to your attribute type. That AttributeData also gives you two properties:

- NamedArguments which covers your `Property = ...` syntax
- ConstructorArguments which is the array of the arguments as being passed to the constructor. You can figure out which constructor it is looking at the AttributeConstructor property. If you want to say "give me the argument for the constructor parameter named foo", figure out the index of the argument in the constructor and then look at that same index in the ConstructorArguments collection.

Answer (score 1):

Since I was searching for something very similar for `IIncrementalGenerator` and this post was constatnly showing up I will post solution for `IIncrementalGenerator` here.

> TLDR; you need to call:
> `syntaxContext.SemanticModel.GetOperation(expressionSyntax)!.ConstantValue!.Value!`

```
    [Generator]
    public class ResourcesToEnumGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
    {
    
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            context.SyntaxProvider.CreateSyntaxProvider(<your attribute filter here>, (syntaxContext, cToken)=>
            {
                var attributeSyntax = (AttributeSyntax)syntaxContext.Node;
                var expressionSyntax = attributeSyntax.ArgumentList!.Arguments[0].Expression
                var argumentValue = (string)syntaxContext.SemanticModel.GetOperation(expressionSyntax)!.ConstantValue!.Value!
            })
            context.RegisterSourceOutput(TriggerFactory.Get(context), GenerateCode);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a friend of mine:

There doesn't seem to be any public API to get the resolved attribute object or a copy of it. The closest thing is SemanticModel.GetReferencedDeclaration which gives you the declaration the attribute is on but not the attribute itself. You can get the attribute's name from the declaration's Name property and the attribute's type from the Type property, so you could write some code like this:

```
var attribute = declaration.GetReferencedDeclaration().Type.GetGenericTypeArguments()[0];

var first = int.Parse(attribute.Name.Substring(0, 1));
var second = int.Parse(attribute.Name.Substring(1));
var third = int.Parse(attribute.Name.Substring(2));
```

Alternatively, you could use the Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() method to get the type of the attribute and then use the Type.GetGenericArguments() method to get the type's arguments.